# How to install/upgrade to Windows 8.1 RTM without a Microsoft account

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-8.1, windows-8-upgrade, windows-live

When I installed Windows 8, I deliberately chose **not** to use a Microsoft account to sign in. I like to keep things separate, and just logon with a traditional local account. Any apps that require me to sign-in with my Live account, will have to prompt me to sign-in.

Now, I just updated to 8.1, but towards the end of the setup process, I was asked to sign-in with a Microsoft account or create one.

Unlike when installing Windows 8, there didn't seem to be any option to skip that step, or otherwise close the sign-in prompt and continue to my updated Windows installation. At least not that I could find.

This is particular annoying, when setting up computers for friends and family, whom I support. They may not have, or have any interest in getting, a Microsoft account and I'm reluctant to use my own.

I realize I can disconnect my Microsoft account after the fact, but is there really no way to install, or upgrade to, Windows 8.1, without being forced to create a Microsoft account? If there is, how does one go about that?

Comment: Could you create a MS Account, then switch your profile to a local one?

Comment: @kobaltz: I could, but why should I be forced to, instead of leaving me with the choice, like Windows 8 did? As noted, this is particular annoying when installing PC's for others.

Comment: I will confirm that you can indeed use Windows 8.1 without a `Microsoft Account` this of course was my experience with an upgrade installation.  I have not bothered trying a clean installation.

Comment: @Ramhound: My experience stems from (two) upgrades, not clean installs. How did you bypass the prompt to sign-in with a Microsoft account? They don't exactly make it clear on the screen, how to do that.

Comment: @abstrask - It might have been because my Virtual Machine didn't have an internet connection.  All I know is that I was able to bypass it.

Comment: I was able to skip it without any problems on my VM.  My system was connected to the network.  Just click the option to create an account, on the next menu there will be an option to skip the creation of a MS account.

Comment: @Zoredache: Thanks - another convoluted way, to skip creating an account. To be honest, I didn't think of clicking to create an account, since I had no interest in doing so. MS really do not want you to *not* link a Microsoft account, huh?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

At the dialog to enter your online account data, click on the button to create a new account,

[image]

here you have a new button to use a local account. It may say "Sign in with your existing account" instead of the "Sign in without a Microsoft Account" message/link shown below.

[image]

Answer (score 21):

**Method 1:**

1. Disconnect your Internet connection before installing Windows 8.1 (or after the first part of installation has finished). Windows detects at some point if there is an active Internet connection – if it isn’t available, it will skip the screen where Windows wants you to Connect this PC to your Microsoft account and offer you to create a local account instead. This is the simplest method of skipping this screen.

**Method 2:**

You can keep your Internet connection enabled. When a screen called Connect this PC to your Microsoft account appears it will ask you for Email Address and Password (for Outlook.com or similar Microsoft service). If you have one you may put it in or if you don’t have it (or use Gmail instead), you have an option to create one. I suppose you want neither otherwise you wouldn’t be reading this right?

1. If you don’t want to create Microsoft account enter some invalid email here for example:

   Email Address: **localhost@localhost.localhost**

   Password: **whatever you like, doesn’t matter (I entered 12345678).**
2. Windows will now check this account and conclude that there was a problem with logging into this account (as it obviously doesn’t exist).
3. On the side a text will appear – “The email address or password is incorrect. If you don’t remember your password, create a local account now and set up your Microsoft account later.”

Source: http://www.infobyte.hr/blog/337/windows-8-1-preview-how-to-install-without-microsoft-account-skip-microsoft-account/

**Method 3:**

> Click on *Create New Account*
>
> Select *Sign In Without Microsoft Account*

Comment: Wow. How stupidly convoluted! Basically, instead of giving me a clear choice, I can either fake forgetting my password, or a lack of internet connection. I didn't like the way MS pushed for one to create a MS account with Windows 8, and I most certainly don't like how they are practially forcing you now. Thanks, Microsoft!

Comment: This trick with disconnection also works to add new local users via Control Panel.

Answer (score 3):

According to TweakGuides.com you can use a local account. During the update...

1. When prompted... click on 'Create a new account'.
2. At the bottom of the next screen (with all the new account info) click on 'Sign in without a Microsoft Account'. It will use your existing local account.

You don't need to disconnect the internet, setup a fake email, or remove the account later.

The author berates Microsoft for deliberately hiding the option as an obvious attempt to trick users into using a Microsoft Account.

http://www.tweakguides.com/Windows81_3.html

Comment: Hi Brett. This is basically what @magicandre1981 wrote. My view resonates with the author of the article you link to :)

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want 8.1 to ask for your microsoft account after installation with the account, after your log in go  to Settings => Change PC settings => Accounts => Your Account, select the option to disconnect. It will prompt you to create a local user pre-selecting the one that existed before. Once disconnected to the Microsoft account, it will login with the re-created account.

Comment: This doesn't answer the OPs question of *"is there [a] way to install, or upgrade to, Windows 8.1, without being forced to **create** a Microsoft account?"*

Answer (score -3):

I am upgrading a new Lenovo Laptop that has factory installed Win 8.0 Basic with all of the vendor crap installed.
I did the Win Store Upgrade to Win 8.1 and after about 3 hours of this and that I was presented with the sign on with MS Internet account.
Here is the trick to get out of it:
HOLD DOWN ON/OFF button until machine drops power.

Then, when you restart you will be presented with the original Win 8.0 login name request that was set up on original install.

This seems to be the easiest way to bypass Microsoft's dictatorial madness.

kentek

Comment: To be honest I find the other solutions better. What other first run customisations are canceled, by shutting down the PC midway? The other solutions use built-in ways to skip the online account step.

Comment: This has the virtue of being simple, but as @abstrask says, the risk of side effects is a little high when there are alternatives.

Comment: How is the simplest way simply to skip the process?