# Using OneDrive with a Domain User account on Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, onedrive, windows-domain

Is there any workarounds for getting OneDrive to work on a Windows domain account? I have connected my domain account to my personal Microsoft account however OneDrive does not work. The modern UI OneDrive app only says *"There was a problem opening this location.. Please try again"* The `%USERPROFILE%\OneDrive` folder is also empty...

I have tried a clean install of Windows 8.1 as well as fresh domain profiles... I remember SkyDrive used to work perfectly with my Microsoft connected domain account in Windows 8.

Is anyone else experiencing this or have a solution please?

**EDIT:** Just to add, if I create a seperate user account on my computer using my Microsoft account, Settings Sync and OneDrive etc works perfectly. This is only happening with my Windows Domain account.

---

**PC Settings**

[image]

**OneDrive App**

[image]

**Windows Explorer**

[image]

Comment: You can use the tool Syncdriver as described here: http://superuser.com/questions/732172/how-can-i-sync-skydrive-onedrive-on-windows-8-1-when-signing-in-to-pc-with-local/732256#732256

Answer (score 1):

Use the latest OneDrive sync client (or "Next Gen Sync Client") as it allows you to sync personal and OneDrive for Business accounts to domain joined and non-domain joined computers.

https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Get-started-with-the-new-OneDrive-sync-client-in-Windows-615391c4-2bd3-4aae-a42a-858262e42a49

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround for this issue, though not really a fix it does mean that the inbuilt OneDrive functionality and also the "Modern UI" OneDrive app behaves as it would on a non domain account.

1. Get to the "User Profiles" control.
   a. By going to Control Panel -> User Accounts -> Configure advanced user profile properties
   b. By going to Control Panel -> System -> Advanced system settings -> Clicking the middle "Settings" under the User Profiles section in the Advanced tab.
2. Select your domain account and click the "Change Type" button and change the account type from Roaming profile to Local Profile.

[image]
[image]

3. Reboot and launch the "Modern UI" OneDrive app.

Despite changing this setting, my profile is still being synced to our logon server during daily use and on logoff. I personally haven't experienced any issues.

I hope this works for somebody else!