# How to create a local user without e-mail request

Tags: windows-8.1, user-accounts

I just want to create a new system user for my running local program.. but microsoft made it difficult to do, now I need an e-mail and theny dont let me change the login....

I want to be able to do the same user management I was used to in previours windows version..

any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install/upgrade to Windows 8.1 RTM without a Microsoft account](http://superuser.com/questions/661416/how-to-install-upgrade-to-windows-8-1-rtm-without-a-microsoft-account). Also see [Disconnect Microsoft account from my local account](http://superuser.com/questions/716107/disconnect-microsoft-account-from-my-local-account).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft made it discouraging to do this but not impossible.

When you must sign in, there's a button saying: `Login with your Live account`
When you click it, there will be a button called `Register live account`. If you click this, at the bottom, there will be a link saying `Create local account instead`.

Using this way, you will create a local account. Additionally, if you already registered an account and logged in with it, you can go to `PC Settings`, `User accounts` and choose to `switch to Local account`, which will create a local account based on the current logged in account. This is a useful technique to store your settings into a live account and quickly apply them after a new installation. Login with the live account once, then switch back to a local account.