# Windows 8.1 Installation Email Account

Tags: windows, email, user-accounts

This is the scenario, I bought a laptop from dell which has windows 8.1 installed on it, I let the guy from dell configure the operating system, now, when I want to add an account, I discovered that I should create an account in Microsoft to be able to add an account on the laptop, I am just wondering how can the guy from dell configure my local account, did he add an email? an email that I dont know? or is it possible to configure windows 8.1 without adding an email account just a local account, if he add an email just to be able to create my local, how can I discover it? Can someone help me on this, I search the internet and search about how to change the email address associated with my local account, but I cant do the procedure because the options are not available in my laptop, I am wondering maybe the guy from dell only add a local account, attach here is the picture that I am talking about, please can someone tell me if I only have a local account

Comment: OEMs often have special software --- provided by Microsoft --- for installing the operating system. By the way, it is possible to add a local account yourself, but it is obscured by the new app interface.

Comment: Also, logically grouping this into paragraphs would make it much easier to read.

Comment: I submitted an answer.  Based on the questions you actually asked.  Honestly I would just create a new user, then connect that user, to a Microsoft Account of your choice.  Without the picture its hard to consider this question helpful to the community.

Answer (score 1):

> I am just wondering how can the guy from dell configure my local
>   account, did he add an email?

The very first intial boot after Windows is installed and the first user is created, there is an option to create a local user that isn't connected to your Microsoft account, its not 100% obvious but its also not hidden.

> or is it possible to configure windows 8.1 without adding an email
>   account just a local account, if he add an email just to be able to
>   create my local, how can I discover it?

Of course it is.  There is an existing question and answer with [details instructions](https://superuser.com/questions/661416/how-to-install-upgrade-to-windows-8-1-rtm-without-a-microsoft-account?rq=1) on how to do it.