# How to install/upgrade to Windows 10 RTM without a Microsoft account

Tags: microsoft-account, windows-10

Does Windows 10 still wants to logon with a Microsoft account instead of a local account? If yes, is there a way to workaround this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Microsoft still wants to push the usage of a Microsoft account in Windows 10.

In the [OOBE phase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out-of-box_experience) you get the option to sign in with a Microsoft Account.

But you can click on `Skip this step`

[image]

and in the nest step you can create a local account:

[image]

In `Who is going to use this PC?` enter the preferred username, now enter your password twice and a hint to not forget it.

That is all and a [1 step lower compared to Windows 8.1](https://superuser.com/a/661592/174557).

Comment: I believe this has changed slightly in the final versions of Windows-10, but is essentially the same.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch no, I just installed the RTM again and took the screenshots again. In the preview it looked different. Today a lot of users will ask this,